# NULL comparison, take 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison, null

I have a subquery, used in WHERE section:

```
A.column <> B.column
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, if either A.column or B.column is NULL. So, I converted it to:

```
((A.column <> B.column) OR ((A.column IS NULL) <> (B.column IS NULL)))
```

, presuming that "Table.column IS NULL" is boolean value and I can compare 2 boolean values. But...

> Incorrect syntax near '<'.

I don't like

```
((A.column <> B.column) OR ((A.column IS NULL) AND (B.column IS NOT NULL)) OR
((A.column IS NOT NULL) AND (B.column IS NULL)))
```

How could I workarounf this?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NULLIF yields null when two values are equal =)

```
WHERE NULLIF(A.column, B.column) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Does not work. if A.column is null the result will always be null even if B.column is not null.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms184325.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

```
(ISNULL(A.column,0)) <> (ISNULL(B.column,0))
```

Comment: Isn't that going to treat 0 and NULL identically? A row with `A=0` and `B=NULL` won't be selected.

Comment: As paxdiablo wrote, I have to have a never-used value. Unfortunately, I have no such values. Even worse, to use ISNULL, I have to know column type. I'd better use ((NULL AND NOT NULL) OR (NOT NULL AND NULL)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use

```
WHERE NOT(A <=> B)
```

To do a `WHERE A <> B` that also works on null.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to